# Upgrading 13.10 to 14.04 alongside a windows 7 installation

Tags: upgrade, 14.04

I have dual boot on my laptop: - Windows 7 with Ubuntu 13.10 installed alongside.

How do I upgrade my ubuntu installation to 14.04 without affecting the Windows installation?

Comment: Not a duplicate.
I know how to upgrade in the normal fashion.
I have never upgraded alongside an already installed Windows 7

Comment: Have you read all the answers?

Comment: Yup.  None that I have seen give details of what I am looking for.
I wish to upgrade by method of a fresh install of 14.04 over the top of the 13.10 installation without affecting the Windows 7 install.
I guess it will be in the something else option but I am unsure exactly what i should be doing.

Comment: Please **edit your question above.** Clearly indicate what you have said in the comments. You should get an option to upgrade in the install menu See http://i.stack.imgur.com/QB7SV.png. It **should** not affect Windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing using a live USB, installing 14.04 in the 13.10 partition will not affect your windows.
If you are using this method (works also for 14.04 final) http://itsfoss.com/upgrade-ubuntu-1404-beta-1310/ It should also not affect your windows. Your windows will be affected if you install ubuntu on Window's partition